# How can I change malloc to new notation in c++

Tags: c++

I have this portion of c++ code, below there are two lines using `malloc` and I want to change it to `new` notation.

```
struct CodingTree* createCodingTree(unsigned int capacity){ 

    struct CodingTree* cTree = (struct CodingTree*)malloc(sizeof(struct cTree));
    
    cTree->size = 0; 

    cTree->capacity = capacity; 

    cTree->array = (struct BinaryNode**)malloc(cTree-> 
capacity * sizeof(struct BinaryNode*)); 
    return cTree; 
}
```

For the first one, I've changed :

```
struct CodingTree* cTree = (struct CodingTree*)malloc(sizeof(struct cTree));
```

to

```
CodingTree* cTree = new CodingTree();
```

And seems like it's working, but for the second one, I have no idea what would be the equivalent `new`.

For reference, adding the `CodingTree` and `BinaryNode` structures.

```
struct BinaryNode{
    char symbol;
    unsigned int count;
    struct BinaryNode *left, *right;
    BinaryNode(char symbol, unsigned int count){
        this->symbol = symbol;
        this->count = count;
        left =0;
        right =0;
    }
};


struct CodingTree { 

    unsigned int size; 

    unsigned int capacity; 

    BinaryNode** array; 
};
```

Comment: This is a case of not seeing the forest for the trees. Has it occurred to you that most of this scaffolding is reinventing a well-known wheel called a "vector"? Instead of sinking time into merely replacing `malloc` with `new`, instead replacing most of this stuff with `std::vector`, and calling it a day, is going to be much, much simpler. Nothing to `malloc` or `new`, the vector will do everything for you. Your `CodingTree` will have just one member `std::vector<BinaryNode>`. All code that deals with `capacity` and `size` gets flushed down the drain. The End.

Comment: Change `cTree->array = (struct BinaryNode**)malloc(cTree-> 
capacity * sizeof(struct BinaryNode*)); ` to `cTree->array = new BinaryNode*[cTree->capacity];`

Comment: If allocation was with `malloc()`, then deallocation will be with `free()`, you can't just change `malloc()` to `new()` without also changing the deallocation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And seems like it's working, but for the second one, I have no idea on
> what would be the equivalent new for reference adding the CodingTree
> and BinaryNode structures.

It seems like what you want is:

```
cTree->array = new BinaryNode*[cTree->capacity];
```

Now this requires you to also change `free` into `delete` (and `delete[]` for arrays). `delete`/`delete[]` will call the proper destructor whereas `free` won't. Calling `free` on memory allocated with `new` is undefined behaviour; there's no guarantee that `malloc` and `new` allocate from same heap.

---

Though it's better if you follow the advice given in the comment, to use `std::vector` for this.

Comment: What happens if `free()` is called somewhere else? (worth a sentence or two)